# How do I use a for loop to return values from a key that features in all the dictionaries stored in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key-value-store

How do I use a for loop to return all the ssn values from the dictionaries stored in this list:

````
patlist = [{'mrn': 7182, 'birthyear': 1989, 'ssn': '999-76-5071', 'fname': 'Edgar', 'lname': 'Hermann', 'zip': 72034},
            {'mrn': 7491, 'birthyear': 2018, 'ssn': '999-92-3312', 'fname': 'Dionna', 'lname': 'Heathcote', 'zip': 72411},
            {'mrn': 7052, 'birthyear': 2013, 'ssn': '999-80-4418', 'fname': 'Eleni', 'lname': 'Gusikowski', 'zip': 72736},
            {'mrn': 4851, 'birthyear': 2011, 'ssn': '999-51-6410', 'fname': 'Ricardo', 'lname': 'Mills', 'zip': 72046},
            {'mrn': 1744, 'birthyear': 1969, 'ssn': '999-72-5953', 'fname': 'Michelle', 'lname': 'Breitenberg', 'zip': 72472}]```
````

Here is one of my attempts:

```
for value in patlist['ssn']:
    print['ssn']
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `for value in patlist: print (value['ssn'])`?

Comment: That's it! Thank you! This worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `patlist` is list of dictionaries, the `value` is actually a dictionary. So you can do `value['ssn']` to print the value of `ssn` key.

```
patlist = [{'mrn': 7182, 'birthyear': 1989, 'ssn': '999-76-5071', 'fname': 'Edgar', 'lname': 'Hermann', 'zip': 72034},
            {'mrn': 7491, 'birthyear': 2018, 'ssn': '999-92-3312', 'fname': 'Dionna', 'lname': 'Heathcote', 'zip': 72411},
            {'mrn': 7052, 'birthyear': 2013, 'ssn': '999-80-4418', 'fname': 'Eleni', 'lname': 'Gusikowski', 'zip': 72736},
            {'mrn': 4851, 'birthyear': 2011, 'ssn': '999-51-6410', 'fname': 'Ricardo', 'lname': 'Mills', 'zip': 72046},
            {'mrn': 1744, 'birthyear': 1969, 'ssn': '999-72-5953', 'fname': 'Michelle', 'lname': 'Breitenberg', 'zip': 72472}]


for value in patlist:
    print(value['ssn'])
```